# CSS - Only select the first set of classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how to only select the first set of a class and apply CSS to it.

In the code below I'm trying to apply a color on the first set of div's with the class **.item**

```
<div class="field-items">
  <div class="item">This text should be red</div>
  <div class="item">This text should be red</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="item">This text should NOT be red</div>
      <div class="item">This text should NOT be red</div>
      <div class="item">This text should NOT be red</div>
      <div class="item">This text should NOT be red</div>
    </div>
  <div class="item">This text should be red</div>
  <div class="item">This text should be red</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the second set of **.item** div's is also getting the **color: red;** css.
I've been playing around with selectors like :nth-child, :nth-of-type, >, +,... but I can't figure out how to do this.

The best I can come up right now is to override the css for the second set.

```
.item {
  color: #cc3333;    
}
.item .item {
  color: #000;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.item .item` wouldn't match any of the inner `.item`s you have since the inner `.field-items` is actually a child of the outer `.field-items`. You probably meant `.field-items .field-items .item`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to find out what element is the parent of the top-level `.field-items`, then attach it to the selector along with `>` combinators. For example if your parent element is `.parent`:

```
.parent > .field-items > .item {
  color: #cc3333;
}
```

Using `.field-items > .item` alone is not enough since you also have `.field-items` nested within `.field-items`, both of which have `.item` children.

Comment: This did the trick, I forgot about the parent selector... silly me. Thanks for the help, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is css without adding class

```
.field-items:first-child > .item{color:red;}
```

Comment: This assumes the outer `.field-items` is the first child while the inner one is not. Note that "first child" doesn't mean outermost element.